# Ruby idiomatic way to return a boolean

Tags: ruby

Is there a more idiomatic way for me to return a boolean in `#survey_completed?`
This is how I did things in C#, and I have always felt that the last ternary clause to return `false` was redundant, so perhaps Ruby has a better way of doing this?

This is how what my code currently looks like:

```
  def survey_completed?
    self.survey_completed_at ? true: false
  end

  def survey_completed_at
    # Seeing as the survey is submitted all or nothing, the time the last response is persisted
    # is when the survey is completed
    last_response = self.responses.last
    if last_response
      last_response.created_at
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use double negation:

```
def survey_completed?
  !!survey_completed_at
end
```

Comment: in general, be careful with `!!` if your input is string, since it will return true for blank string and that might ot be desired behaviour. Just FYI

Comment: @IuriG. in this case activesupport `Object#present?` is useful.

Comment: @MarekLipka `Object#present?` is a rails extension. Assuming you are using rails core extensions then yes, `Object#present?` would be better.

Comment: @IuriG. yes, I even wrote this method comes from activesupport.

Answer (score 2):

```
  def survey_completed?
    !survey_completed_at.nil?
  end
```

Comment: This will return `true` if `survey_completed_at` is `false`, which may or may not be expected.

Comment: survey_completed_at is a datetime field

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to do this in Ruby is to not do it. Every object except for `false` and `nil` evaluates to `true` in a Boolean context. Thus your `survey_completed_at` function already serves the purpose of the `survey_completed?` function.

If you got a response for the survey, `last_response.created_at` will be something non-nil thus the function will evaluate to `true` in a Boolean context. If you didn't get a response and `last_response` is `nil`, the if will evaluate to `nil` and the function will evaluate to `false` in a Boolean context.